# Дореформенная грамматика

Tags: грамматика

1) В 7-м абзаце предисловия: "...Онъ пришелъ въ міръ, чтобы сообщить людямъ благовѣстіе о вѣчной божественной жизни, которое Онъ предподалъ намъ въ простыхъ человѣческихъ словахъ..." - Возможно, правильно будет "преподалъ"?

2) В 1-й части книги, в главе "О монахах", 4-й абзац с конца главы: "...Кто на послушаніи, тотъ хотя и разсеится иногда, но Господь милостивъ къ нему..." - Возможно, правильно будет "разсѣется"?

Comment: Надеюсь, не нарушу правила хорошего тона, сообщая, что книга совсем не дореволюционная, а почти что современная.   
Все разговоры про "отсутствие правил" оказались лишены смысла изначально.  
Ошибки предопределены личностью автора первоисточника.

Все сведения получены от автора вопроса в личке.

Answer (score 3):

Если это книга дореволюционная, то никаких ошибок там быть не может, по причине отсутствия обязательных правил написания. Хотя устоявшиеся традиции и общие рекомендации существовали и тогда, начиная с XVIII века.

Если за норму брать написание наиболее распространённое в XIX-XX вв, когда эти рекомендации более-менее унифицировались, то точнее будет "преподалъ" и "разс**ѣе**тся".

Comment: >никаких ошибок там быть не может, по причине отсутствия обязательных правил написания

*"Произвести измерения температуры забортной воды не представляется возможным ввиду отсутствия таковой!"*. Как в мультике про капитана Врунгеля :-).

Как это отсутствия? Есть у меня старинные книги, так там в разных книгах русские слова вроде бы одинаково пишутся! Ея, коих и т.п. забавные слова.

Comment: @Nikolja , были традиции написания и произношения, не более.  На протяжении XIX века унифицированость орфографии увеличивалась и в начале ХХ века даже вышел Академический словарь, который сейчас и принято считать за норму, но в современном понимании правил написания не существовало.

Для понимания возьмём слово "торрент". Почти все его так пишут и вполне можно сказать, что это норма, но при отсутствии фиксации неологизма в академических словарях, написание "то**рэ**нт" признать ошибкой нельзя.

Comment: >причине отсутствия обязательных правил написания

Бредъ. Причем бредъ очевиднейшiй. Вы хотите сказать, что в гимназiяхъ учили не про правиламъ?  
  
>"преподалъ" и "разсеѣтся"   
   
Васъ изъ какого класса изгнали?  
Гдѣ вы вообщѣ видѣли написанiе корня "сѣять" черезъ "есть"? И откуда ять (буква) въ глагольномъ суффиксѣ глагола на "-ять"? "Сѣй-ать" даетъ въ третьемъ лицѣ "сѣй-этъ".   
А правила Грота никто не отмѣнялъ.

Comment: Прошу прощения за опечатку, не туда "ѣ" вставил. А вот правила Грота - это наиболее авторитетное пособие по русской орфографии до 1918 года, но не обязательная норма. "вядчина" вместо ветчина и "діэта" вместо діета, несмотря на рекомендации Якова Карловича писали редко.

Comment: Ну так и сейчас есть граждане, которым законы (в смысле - Правила) не писаны. Зачем поминать-то?

А если обязательных правил не было, о чем тогда говорят в приснопамятном декрете об отмене ятей и еров?

Comment: @behemothus, потому что отсутствие обязательной нормы **для всех**, не означает отсутствие норм ограниченных.

Что бы увидеть существовавший разнобой, достаточно просто посмотреть на алфавит в дореволюционных изданиях. Грот написал, что "ижица можетъ считаться исключенною изъ русской азбуки", и это молча приняли. В дореволюционных учебниках и словарях, однако, разнобой: в одних она вообще не упоминается, в других — упоминается в скобках или с пометкой, что слова на ижицу искать надо под "и", а в третьих числится в алфавите как ни в чем не бывало. Причем от года издания это не зависит.

Comment: Это ни говоря о диалектной орфографии, которую Грот не затрагивал, но вполне себе допускал (см. рассуждение о слове "батюшко").

Кстати, сейчас по некоторым словам, тоже уже наблюдается исчезновение норм. В итоге можно писать *Государственная дума* (по Лопатину), *государственная дума* (по Розенталю), *Государственная Дума* (по требованию самих депутатов).

Comment: Марк Из, это банальные рассуждения ни о чем.   
Правила были, то, что некоторые граждане их не соблюдали или не знали, равно как и некоторые спорные и неоднозначные моменты, *не отменяет* само ***существование*** орфографических (и пунктуационных) норм. Я Вам приводил пример декрета о переходе на новую орфографию. Так русским по белому о том, что все *старые* нормы действуют, за исключением перечисленных. 
Вы, похоже, просто догматизируете сам факт появления Свода-56. Каковой тоже, кстати, не является общепринятым и . Просто потому, что у Академии Наук нет и не было полномочий законодателя.

Answer (score 1):

О какой книге вы говорите? Если это какое-то совсем древнее издание, то в них опечаток (в том числе и связанных с недостаточной грамотностью) было предостаточно.

Слово "предподалъ" вполне возможно, значение то же, что и преподалъ, но более возвышенный стиль.

Что касается "разсеится" то оно действительно вызывает некоторые сомнения. По всем правилам оно писалось через ять и относилось к первому (по современной нумерации) спряжению. Причем - во всех значениях.

Comment: Оставил "предподалъ" без изменения, "разсеится" изменил на "разсѣется". Спаси Христос! К сожалению, для того, чтобы одобрять сообщения, мне не хватает каких-то "баллов уважения":) Простите!

Comment: **Так а что за книга**, @Паша777, можно поинтересоваться? Вы так подробно в своём вопросе номера глав и даже абзацов называли, а саму книгу так пока и не назвали, несмотря на *наши* вопросы. Любопытно. 

Это современное христианское издание? Репринт чего-то дореволюционного? Или из эмиграции?

Comment: Паша777, баллами я с Вами поделился.